# "deferencing pointer to Incomplete type" error in c

Tags: c, structure

I have two structures like this

**CODE EDITED:**

```
typedef struct 
{
   int threadId;
   void *stack;
}gtthread_t;

typedef struct
{
   gtthread_t *th;
   struct list *next;
}list;
```

In my code, i have used the structures like:

```
list *temp;
gtthread_t thread;
if(temp->next->th->threadId != thread.threadId && temp->next!=NULL) //error generated here
{
   //do something
}
```

The error is also occuring here:

```
free(temp->next->th->stack);
```

What am i doing wrong here? I have a node in temp->next (it is not NULL).

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Your definition of `list` has an error, a compiler should complain on the `list *next;` line because `list` is not yet defined at that line. Please post a complete minimal source file that exhibits the problem.

Comment: will this even compile? This is C so you need to specify 'struct list* next' in your struct list.

Comment: The code you posted is not real code. Trying to guess what happens in your actual code by this unrelated example is a waste of time.

Comment: Extremely sorry. I have edited the code. I am getting the same error.

Comment: I wonder if you have some wierd naming clash - maybe with a macro. Have you tried changing `list` to `Hari` or somesuch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rewrite the list like this;

```
struct list
{
   gtthread_t *th;
   struct list *next;
};
typedef struct list list;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
typedef struct
{
   gtthread_t *th;
   list *next;
}list;
```

When the parser is at  line 3, it has no idea what `list` means. Try

```
typedef struct list
{
   gtthread_t *th;
   struct list *next;
}list;
```

instead.

Answer (score -1):

This structure also needs to be created: `temp->next->th->threadId`

i.e.

```
temp = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
temp->next = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
temp->next->th = (gtthread_t *)malloc(sizeof(gtthread_t));
temp->next->th->threadId = <some value>
temp->next->th->stack = <some value>
```